# Spring WebFlux - no JSP support?

Tags: spring-webflux

I was trying to configure Spring WebFlux with JSP. I don't see any View class for supporting JSTL views in Spring WebFlux.
Does this mean that we can't develop a JSP application using Spring WebFlux?

Thanks, AJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebFlux is not tied to the Servlet specification so JSP support cannot be consistently implemented across deployment options.

Comment: Is there any plan to provide JSP support ? I see that Freemarker and Thymleaf support is already there.